# How can i apply SharedPreferences in this code?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

This is my first 'legit project' in android and java as well. It is a simple counter with additional features [most of which yet to be added]. I'm stuck with a problem where I can't save the count when user closes the app. Suppose if some as tapped till 50 and then just closes the app (not just exit but CLOSES the whole app) so on re-opening, I want it to continue from 50.

I know I can do this with shared preferences but I have tried to do it on my own and watched some YouTube videos as well but for no avail. It just won't work or the app crashes.

If some one can have a look at my code and help me add the required shared preference code then it would be amazing and I am also planning to add a **setting page/activity** from options menu in which I want to keep light/dark theme switching.

```
package com.example.tapcounter;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Switch;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private AdView mAdView ;
    private int counter = 0;
    TextView txt;
    Button btnU,btnT,btnR;
    Switch sw;

    private static long back_pressed;

    //Double Tap Exit
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        if (back_pressed + 2000 > System.currentTimeMillis()) super.onBackPressed();
        else Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Press once again to exit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        back_pressed = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }


    //Inflater for Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu,menu);
        return true;

    }

    //Menu
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menui1:
                Intent aboutIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(aboutIntent);
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        MobileAds.initialize(this, "AppID");
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        btnT =  findViewById(R.id.tapbtn);
        btnR =  findViewById(R.id.resetbtn);
        btnU =  findViewById(R.id.undobtn);
        sw = findViewById(R.id.swch);
        txt =  findViewById(R.id.txtv);

;


        //TAP Button
        btnT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter ++;
                txt.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                
            }
        });


        //UNDO Button
        btnU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(counter > 0) {
                    counter--;
                    txt.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
                }
                else{
                    return;
                }
            }
        });

        //RESET Button
        btnR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                counter = 0;
                txt.setText(Integer.toString(counter));
            }
        });

        //Lock Switch
        sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(sw.isChecked()) {
                    btnR.setEnabled(false);
                    btnT.setEnabled(false);
                    btnU.setEnabled(false);
                }
                else{
                    btnR.setEnabled(true);
                    btnT.setEnabled(true);
                    btnU.setEnabled(true);
                }
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Don't know if xml code is necessary but here ya go.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/BG"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/BG"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/undobtn"
            android:layout_width="103dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/undobtnS"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.051"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tapbtn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resetbtn"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:text="@string/restbtnS"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tapbtn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/swch"
            android:layout_width="102dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
            android:text="@string/swchS"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.948"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tapbtn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.748" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/txtvS"
            android:textSize="130sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tapbtn"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.325" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tapbtn"
            android:layout_width="415dp"
            android:layout_height="450dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="92dp"
            android:alpha="0.1"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="SMART_BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/tapbtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. `It just won't work or the app crashes.` always include the error logs or explain what isn't working and add the code you've tried, asking for complete code here isn't really appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to save counter value when activity lifecycle's `onStop` or `onDestroy` method called and in `onResume` or `onCreate` method you have to retrieve that value.

To save integer values using Shared Preferences :

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor =  getContext().getSharedPreferences("NAME_OF_SHARED_PREF" , MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putInt("KEY_NAME_HERE" , COUNTER_INT_VALUE_HERE);
```

and you can retrieve value like this :

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("NAME_OF_SHARED_PREF", MODE_PRIVATE);
int counter = prefs.getInt("KEY_NAME_HERE", ANY_DEFAULT_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a shared preference in this way

```
   public class MySharedPref {

      //Shared Preferences
        SharedPreferences pref;

      //Editor for Shared preferences
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

      //context
        Context context;

      //shared pref mode
        int PRIVATE_MODE=0;

      //shared pref file name
       public static final String PREF_NAME="MySharedPref";


       public MySharedPref(Context context){
            this.context=context;
            pref=context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME,PRIVATE_MODE);
            editor=pref.edit();
        }

        public void changeCount(String count){
             editor.putString("Count",count);
             editor.commit();
          }

        public String getCount(){
             return pref.getString("Count","0");
        }
      }
```

Then in your MainActivity you can use it as-

```
    MySharedPref mySharedPref; //declare it

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       mySharedPref=new MySharedPref(getApplicationContext());
       //other part
    }

     //TAP Button
    btnT.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter ++;
            mySharedPref.changeCount(Integer.toString(counter));
            //other part
        }
    });


    //UNDO Button
    btnU.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(counter > 0) {
                counter--;
                mySharedPref.changeCount(Integer.toString(counter));
                //other part
            }
            else{
                return;
            }
        }
    });

    //RESET Button
    btnR.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            counter = 0;
            mySharedPref.changeCount(Integer.toString(counter));
            //other part
        }
    });
```

You can get the last count saved after re-opening by using `mySharedPref.getCount()` like

```
      txt.setText(mySharedPref.getCount());
```

Hope it helps

Comment: The number did got saved but every time when I tap the counter [button  (btnT)], it resets and starts from 1. Maybe its because I initialized the counter = 0 ?

Comment: Yes, it can be, I have not tried. So please try again with it and then let me know.

Comment: I tried it myself but the app either crashed or the problem persisted anyway. can't wrap my head around this one..

Comment: nvm, I changed the whole code. I realized that the way I wanted it to work was not possible with the current code. Its working now. Finally !

Comment: I am glad that it works great. Did my answer helped you? Let me know I will be happy if it helps

Comment: kinnndaaaa.. it helped to understand me the basics

Comment: Okay glad to know that it helps. You can accept it as the answer to this question if it helped.